# Why my animation is slow in Ipad

Tags: jquery, performance, ipad, animation

I'm building a group of jquery animations, my animations are wonderful in Desktop, but when I tested it in the Ipad it showed very slow. I want to know, why it is so slow in the ipad
Here is my Jquery code.

```
  /* --------------------------------SLIDE DO ASIDE --------------------------------*/

  $("#wrapper div.targe").on('pointerdown', function() {
    $(this).next("div.discuss").next(".afteraside").toggleClass("after_discuss");
    $(this).next("div.discuss").toggle("slide", {direction: "right"}, 400);
    return false;
  });


  /* --------------------------------NOTA DE RODAPÉ --------------------------------*/


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#wrapper img.footnote").next().css("display", "none");
  $('nav').localScroll({ duration: 300 });
  $('#wrapper div.slick').slick({
          dots: false,
          arrows: false,
          draggable: true,
          speed: 500,
          touchMove: false
        });
});

  $("#wrapper img.footnote").on('pointerdown', function() {

    $(this).toggleClass("footchange");
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
        /*.addClass("hidden_footnote")*/

    if($(this).hasClass("footchange")) {
      $(this).attr("src", "image/hide_fnt.png");
    }
    else {
      $(this).attr("src", "image/show_fnt.png");
    }
    return false;
  });


  /* ------------------------SLIDE EXERCICIOS------------------------ */

  $("#wrapper img.imagesolucao").on('pointerdown', function() {
    $(this).next("div.solucao").slideToggle();
    return false;
  });

  $("#wrapper div.bloco2").find("li.nextslide").on('pointerdown', function() {
    $(this).closest("div.bloco2").next("div.slick").slickNext();
    $("div.solucao").hide();
  });

  $("#wrapper div.bloco2").find("li.prevslide").on('pointerdown', function() {
    $(this).closest("div.bloco2").next("div.slick").slickPrev();
    $("div.solucao").hide();
  });

  /*---------------------SUBMENU----------------------*/

  $("#nav4 a").on('pointerdown', function(){
    $("ul.submenu").slideToggle();
  });

/*-----------------------AUDIO-----------------------*/

$("#nav6").on('pointerdown', function(){
var audio = $(".home_audio");
audio.toggleClass("audio_on");
if(audio.hasClass("audio_on")) {
  audio.trigger("play");
}
else {
  audio.trigger("pause");
}
});



/*----------------- VERIFICAR ACERTOS -------------*/

function verificarAcertos(){
  var cont = 0;

  $('#wrapper div.radio').find("input[type='radio']").each(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).hasClass("correct_answer")){
      $(this).next('label').css("color", "#022954").css("font-weight", "bold");
      cont++;
      $(this).closest("div.option").closest("div.radio").find("input[type='radio']").attr("disabled", true);
    }

    else if($(this).is(':checked') && !($(this).hasClass("correct_answer"))){
      $(this).next('label').css("color", "red").addClass("label2");
      $(this).attr("disabled", true);
    }
  });

  $("#wrapper p.counting").text(cont);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've noticed that the .attr() slows the iPad down a lot. Accessing the attribute must be done differently to everything else, as my animation is very smooth otherwise.

I've had good luck keeping a separate array with values and looping through those.

Comment out the .attr() lines and try the animation again.